# How to update a field in target Data Extension in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I wrote a query to update a field inside a target Data Extension. The query will set the field to True when a subscriber has received an email within three days. The field has a default value of False.

**Problem:** The query is setting the field inside the target DE to false. How can i update the field inside the Target DE. Here is the query below:

```
Select [Email Address] as [Email Address], contact_three_days as 'True' from initial_emailing_list 

WHERE [Email Address] NOT IN 

(SELECT SubscriberKey FROM _Sent WHERE EventDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. 
If you use 'as' in your select statement then it's renaming you field, not the value. Hard code the value using =

```
Select
 [Email Address] as [Email Address],
 contact_three_days =  'True' 
 from initial_emailing_list 
WHERE [Email Address] NOT IN (SELECT SubscriberKey FROM _Sent WHERE EventDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Set the action to update rather the overwrite the target data extension.

Comment: Thank you @iManage. I need to make edit to my query so that it will give me a Data Extension that is a copy of the Source DE, but has the contact_three_days field set to true for all relevant fields.